# How to make an image of a bootable flash drive without wasting space (as with dd) on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup

I've got a bootable flash memory card with an Ubuntu operating system on it along with other programs, ie. a fully functioning system I use on a single-board computer. I'd like to back it up on my PC's (also running Ubuntu) hard disk, but without wasting space as the `dd` command would do (because it also backs up free space). The flash drive is 32GB big and only 10% full. It doesn't have any partitions on it.

What are the options?

**EDIT** the flash drive is formatted as `ext4`, so `partimage` doesn't apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use dd because with it you can cook very quickly other flash memory:

- set to zero all free space: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/usb_device_dir/ZEROFILL ; rm /media/usb_device_dir/ZEROFILL` this creates a big file filled with zero and then removes it.
- `dd if=/dev/usb_device | bzip2 > os_image.bz2`

Or make a tar of your operating system:

```
cd /media/usb_device_dir
tar jcpvf /home/foo/os_image.tar.bz2 .
```

But before extracting this to a clean flash card, you have to

- format
- add bootable flag
- install a bootloader

Comment: Hi Alessandro. Could you please explain how the first statement creates a "big file"? What is it's size? Should I replace `/dev/zero` with anything, or is it a special command to `dd`?

Comment: And another thing: shouldn't be `rm /media/usb_device_dir/`*ZEROFILL* ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is `/media/usb_device_dir/ZEROFILL` just a copy-paste error. It writes zero to that file until there's no space available.

Comment: Just a note / adding parameter `bs=10M` to the `dd` command speeds up the progress dramatically on my PC

Answer (score 8):

`dd if=/dev/your_usb | lzma -9c > usb_image.bin.lzma` shouldn't waste any space.

Comment: Thanks Let_Me_Be, is there a way to make this particular `dd` command execute a bit faster? Eg. less compression? Is there a way for the `dd` command to output any progress indication? And last but not least, what is the command to uncompress the image to `your_usb` afterwards?

Comment: @mmm `lzcat usb_image.bin.lzma | dd of=/dev/your_usb`

Comment: `pv /dev/your_usb | lzma -9c > usb_image.bin.lzma` wil show progress (requires package `pv` installed).

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume that empty areas on the filesystem are filled with zeros Let_Me_Be's answer applies.

Otherwise have a look at [Partimage](http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page)

Comment: Is it likely that ext3/ext4 will fill empty space with zeroes? I have a feeling that it is not so, but have nothing to back it up but performance considerations.

Comment: Thanks halo, I edited my question, partimage doesn't support ext4, unfortunately.